# How do i show value all fields?Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I use plugin Custom Fields.

I created five fields and I call (`cat_content,imagine2,imagine3,imagine4,imagine5`)

All these values I stored in a vector (`fields`)

I browse the vector with instruction foreach and I tried to show in a list.

Unfortunately, my list is empty ... look at the picture below.

http://i59.tinypic.com/2qx58d4.jpg

This is my site:

[link](http://dgprint.dg-site.com/?product_category=business-card)

```
<div class="container">
                        <?php 
                        $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
                        $cat_content = get_field('category_content', $queried_object);
                        $imagine2= get_field('imagine2',$queried_object);                      
                        $imagine3= get_field('imagine3',$queried_object);                 
                        $imagine4= get_field('imagine4',$queried_object);
                        $imagine5= get_field('imagine5',$queried_object);

                               $fields = array("cat_content","imagine2","imagine3","imagine4","imagine5"); ?>
                                 <ul>
                                  <?php if (is_array($values) || is_object($values)) {?>
                                    <?php foreach($fiedls as $value) { ?>
                                        <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                     <?php } ?>
                                 </ul>
    </div>
```

How can I solve this problem?
I have done wrong in the algorithm code?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I tried to make some changes but all is not well ... look at the picture below

```
http://i58.tinypic.com/1zq3ltx.jpg
```

**This is new CODE:**

```
<div class="container">
                        <?php 
                        $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
                        $cat_content = get_field('category_content', $queried_object);
                        $imagine2= get_field('imagine2',$queried_object);                      
                        $imagine3= get_field('imagine3',$queried_object);                 
                        $imagine4= get_field('imagine4',$queried_object);
                        $imagine5= get_field('imagine5',$queried_object);

                               $fields = array("cat_content","imagine2","imagine3","imagine4","imagine5"); ?>
                                <?php echo $fields; ?>
                                 <ul>
                                  <?php if (is_array($fields) || is_object($fields)) {?>
                                    <?php foreach($fiedls as $value) { ?>
                                        <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                     <?php } ?>
                                 </ul>



                    </div>
```

Comment: A typo... `foreach($fiedls` -> `foreach($fields` ?

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
 <div class="container">
                                <?php 
                                $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
                                $cat_content = get_field('category_content', $queried_object);
                                $imagine2= get_field('imagine2',$queried_object);                      
                                $imagine3= get_field('imagine3',$queried_object);                 
                                $imagine4= get_field('imagine4',$queried_object);
                                $imagine5= get_field('imagine5',$queried_object);

                                       $fields = array($cat_content,$imagine2,$imagine3,$imagine4,$imagine5); ?>
                                        <?php // echo $fields; ?>
                                         <ul>
<?php if (is_array($fields) || is_object($fields)) {?>
                                            <?php foreach( $fields as $value) { ?>
                                                <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                             <?php } ?>
                                         </ul>


                        </div>
```